# getElementById() displaying details of only the first row in a dynamic table

Tags: dynamic-data, getelementbyid

There are 3 functions:

1. for adding rows to a dynamic table using 'add' button

   ```
   var count=0;
   function addRow(tableID) {

       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

       var cel1 = row.insertCell(0);
       var element1 = document.createElement("input");
       element1.type = "checkbox";
       element1.name="chkbox[]"+count;
       element1.id="chk[]"+count;
       cel1.appendChild(element1);


       var cel2 = row.insertCell(1);
       var element2 = document.createElement("input");
       element2.type = "text";
       element2.name = "txtbox[]"+count;
       element2.id="nam[]"+count;
       cel2.appendChild(element2);

       var cel3 = row.insertCell(2);
       var element3 = document.createElement("input");
       element3.type = "text";
       element3.name = "txtbox[]"+count;
       element3.id="cit[]"+count;
       cel3.appendChild(element3);


            count++;

   }
   ```
2. for deleting checked rows from a dynamic table using 'delete' button

   ```
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;

       for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
           var row = table.rows[i];
           var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
           if(chkbox !=null && chkbox.checked==true) {
               table.deleteRow(i);
               rowCount--;
               i--;
           }


       }
   ```
3. for displaying the values entered in the textboxes of each checked row in a new window using 'display details' button

   ```
            function display(tableID){
       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;

       for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {

           var row = table.rows[i];
           var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
           if(chkbox !=null && chkbox.checked==true) {
              var x=(document.getElementById('nam').value);
              var y=(document.getElementById('cit').value);
              document.body.innerHTML="Name: "+x +" City: "+ y;
              //document.body.innerHTML=y;
              //alert(x+","+y);


          }

        }
      }
   ```

The problem is that 'Display Details' Button is showing the values entered in the textboxes of only the first row when it is checked.
The output is blank for the other rows of the table added.

Im trying to display values entered in the textboxes using getElementById().But there are ids only for the first row textboxes. How do i create dynamic ids for the textboxes of the added rows? How do i incorporate the same in the code?

HTML:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="450px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD> </TD>
        <TD>Name </TD>
        <TD> City </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD> <INPUT name="text1" id="nam" type="text" /> </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT name="text2" id="cit" type="text" /> </TD>
    </TR>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Display Details" onclick="display('dataTable');"/>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this the first time through the loop...

```
document.body.innerHTML="Name: "+x +" City: "+ y;
```

...you've nuked the rest of your document, so there's no more table to iterate through.

Instead of replacing the entire document body with that output, append it to some existing element within the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetCellValues() {
var rows = document.getElementById('dataTable').
getElementsByTagName('tbody')    [0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = function() {
       alert(document.getElementById("nam[]"+(this.rowIndex + 1)).value   );

    }
    }

 }
```

I have one cell with id:

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.type = "text";
element2.value="Tipo";
element2.id="nam[]"+count;
cell3.appendChild(element2);
```

And cell type button(for me):

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "button";
element3.value="Enviar e-mail";
element3.onclick= function() { GetCellValues(); };
cell4.appendChild(element3);
```

it´s ok for me.